# Retrofit2 call with RxJava2 sometimes throws IOException (rather than calling onError handler)

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, rx-java2

**tl;dr:** How do I catch IOExceptions (and descendants) when making Retrofit2 calls using RxJava2?

### Discussion

I'm using Retrofit2 with RxJava2. I have designated an onError handler. Nevertheless, my app still crashes sometimes with `IOException`s -- in particular, a `SocketTimeoutException`. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2292) against Retrofit on Github, but I'm wondering if I'm just mis-using it or missing something obvious.

Here is how I'm creating my Retrofit services:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(/* a variety of interceptors */)
        .connectTimeout(10, SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, SECONDS) // first attempt to head off timeout exception
        .build();

RxJava2CallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = 
RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());
Factory gsonFactory = GsonAdapterFactory.gsonConverterFactory();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(endpoint)
        .client(okClient)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
        .addConverterFactory(gsonFactory)
        .build();

return retrofit.create(Thing.class);
```

Example retrofit definition:

```
@GET("/thing")
Flowable<Response<Thing>> getThing();
```

Example call with a retrofit service:

```
service.getThing()
    .map(response -> thingFromResponse(thing)) // here I check for a successful response
    .subscribe(thing -> doStuffWithThing(thing), // Consumer<Thing> onNext
               throwable -> handleError("Error getting thing", throwable) // Consumer<Throwable> onError
    );
```

I would expect my `handleError()` function to handle *all* errors, but instead all descendants of IOException seem to bypass this and crash instead.

The javadoc for `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` states:

> Response wrapped body (e.g., Observable) calls onNext with a Response object for all HTTP responses and calls onError with IOException for network errors.

Nevertheless, I see crashes with this stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:593)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:601)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeResponseHeaders(Http2Stream.java:146)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:120)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:67)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at com.myapp.backend.retrofit.interceptors.SigningInterceptor.intercept(SigningInterceptor.java:32)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at com.myapp.backend.retrofit.interceptors.UserTokenInterceptor.intercept(UserTokenInterceptor.java:28)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at com.myapp.backend.retrofit.interceptors.UserAgentHeaderInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentHeaderInterceptor.java:24)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallObservable.subscribeActual(CallObservable.java:41)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39)
       at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:134)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

### EDIT:

After updating rxjava2 adapter from 1.1.0 (with `com.jakewharton` package) to 2.2.0, I haven't observed the problem again. Either I'm lucky, or that fixed it.

As a final note, I also changed my Retrofit services from returning instances of `Flowable<Response<Thing>>` to `Flowable<Result<Thing>>` to get a direct reference to any `Throwable`s caused by the call. That may have helped, or been redundant.

Comment: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/
checked exceptions must still have a try/catch block

Comment: Please make sure you use the latest versions of the libraries.

Comment: @akarnokd I noticed I was using an old version of the adapter a little while after posting this question. If the error recurs, I'll update, but for now I'll hope this fixes the problem.